# mysql match string with start of string in table

Tags: mysql

I realise that it would be a lot easier if I could modify the table when it was created, but assuming I can't, I have a table that is such as:

```
abcd
abde
abdf
abff
bbsdf
bcggs
... snip large amount
zza
```

The values in the table are not fixed length.
I have a string to match such as abffagpokejfkjs .
If it was the other way round, I could do

```
SELECT * from table where value like 'abff%'
```

but I need to select the value that matches the start of a string that is provided.

Is there a quick way of doing that, or does it need an itteration through the table to find a match?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. What value are you trying to return? Why can you not just use `LEFT(value, 4)` or a `LIKE`?

Comment: I can't use LEFT as I don't know how many characters the result is - could be 1, could be 25. Could loop through all the numbers but doesn't sound fast.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT col1, col2 -- etc...
FROM your_table
WHERE 'abffagpokejfkjs' LIKE CONCAT(value, '%')
```

Note that this will not use an index effectively so it will be slow if you have a lot of records.

Also note that some characters in `value` (e.g. `%`) may be interpreted by LIKE as having a special meaning, which may undesirable.

Answer (score 15):

`LIKE` can be avoided, by truncating the comparison string to each value's length:

```
... WHERE LEFT('abffagpokejfkjs', LENGTH(value)) = value
```

Comment: I had to use `CHAR_LENGTH`. `LENGTH` returns number of bytes, which in case of non-ASCII strings may not be desired.