# Get all rows where string starts with column value

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Using SQLAlchemy, it's easy to get all the rows where a given column starts with a given string. But how do I flip it around so that I get rows where the beginning of the string matches the column?

I.e, if the string is "stackoverflow" I'd want it to match a row with the value "stack"

If necessary, I can store regex in the column instead of just the string, but I don't know how to invert a regex comparison either.

Comment: There is [SQL solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9667309/1296661) : `SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE 'stackoverflow' LIKE CONCAT(column_name, '%')`. But I'm not sure how to build such query with SQLAlchemy expression. `.filter("stackoverflow".like(your_table.column_name))` won't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is [SQL solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9667309/1296661) implemented as sqlalchemy expression

```
class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__="foo_tablename"
    bar = Column(String(80))

bar = 'stackoverflow'
session.query(Foo).filter(literal('stackoverflow').like(func.concat(Foo.bar, '%')))
```

SQLAlchey log shows generated query:

```
>>INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT bar FROM foo_tablename WHERE :param1 LIKE CONCAT(foo_tablename.bar_column,'%')
>>INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'param1': 'stack'}
```

Please note:

- such type of sql query prevents database from using column index - so it is potential performance bottleneck.

So if I would need to add such functionality into production I would consider using full text search feature provided by database. SQLAlchemy doesn't provide support for full text search as it is database specific functionality. See example of [combining PostgreSQL full text search with SQLAlchemy](http://lowmanio.co.uk/blog/entries/postgresql-full-text-search-and-sqlalchemy/).

**Updated**

User [Audrius Kažukauskas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1870151/audrius-kazukauskas) suggested how to get rid of raw sql. So this removes limitations of [using literal SQL](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/tutorial.html#using-literal-sql).

Comment: Nice idea, but no need to write raw SQL, you can do it like the following: `session.query(Foo).filter(literal('stackoverflow').like(func.concat(Foo.bar, '%')))`

Comment: Audrius. Thank you for brilliant suggestion. I updated my answer to include your improved version of query.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's a better way, but this should work:

```
bar = 'stackoverflow'
session.query(Foo).filter(
    Foo.data.in_([bar[:i] for i in xrange(5, len(bar) + 1)])
)
```